# How to compare current date to custom field date

Tags: php, wordpress, timestamp

I have thousands of posts which have custom field of release date and the format of date is **February 24, 2015** and now i have updated my all thousands post to unix timestamp by using `strtotime() function` i want to upcoming movies by comparing current date to custom field date and now in my custom field all dates are in unix timestamp but when i am running query result is not good.

Here is my code

```
$today = 'get_the_date('F j, Y')';
            $today = strtotime($today); 

            $args = array(                
                'paged' => $paged,                
                'post_type'=>$post_types,
                'meta_key'=> 'ct_Released_Y_text_b894',
                'meta_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'ct_Released_Y_text_b894',
                                        'value' => $today,
                                        'compare' => '<',
                                        )
                                ),
                'order_by' => 'meta_value'      
                );              
            query_posts($args);
```

I have edit many times compare value to < , > , <= , >= but all posts showing me not upcoming movies. please help me how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function

```
$args = array(                
                    'paged' => $paged,                
                    'post_type'=>$post_types,
                    'meta_key'=> 'ct_Released_Y_text_b894',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'ct_Released_Y_text_b894',
                                            'value' => time(),
                                            'compare' => '>=',
                                            )
                                    ),
                    'order_by' => 'meta_value_num'    
                    'order' => 'ASC'  
                    );              
                query_posts($args);
```